# In SharePoint Online Library files exceeds the list view threshold, which is 5000 items

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365, document-management

How to deal with this document management because in my organization we got lot of libraries with above the threshold of 5000 items. What is the best approach that we can make to make the documents below threshold or is there any way to increase the threshold of the document library in Office 365.

Will there be any chance of data loss if it is above the threshold value of 5000 in the library?

Answer (score 3):

1st thing, You cannot change that value in Office 365. 2nd thing, even you exceed the number of items then the threshold you will not lose the data rather it will not showed in the view.

Now dealing with the large list there are multiple things you have to think about.

- Use the filtered views with indexed columns, so that it returns always below 5K items.

Check more details here: [Manage large lists and libraries in Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-Office-365-B4038448-EC0E-49B7-B853-679D3D8FB784?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Comment: I have seen some documents are missing in some of the libraries.What else factors can cause the loss of data in a library and i have checked the recycle bin and second stage recycle bin to see if i can find any documents in there but i did not find any. Thanks

Comment: Use open with explorer option.... open the library in windows explorer then check the documents

Answer (score 0):

I'd add that a review of how your document libraries are organized and metadata tagged is worthwhile.

- Are your document libraries focused by division/OU or team? If so, there is there a way to review the way you're structuring how documents are organized by functional unit (Form).
- Are any document libraries/documents being organized by process? (Function)
- The statement "Form follows function" is as relevant to SharePoint design and usage as anything.
- Are using any methods to automate the population of metadata columns against your documents, thereby supporting the building of filtered view to return subsets of documents? Workflow is good for this.
- Are you using a method (such as workflow) to automatically tag related user accounts to documents based on the need by process to access them? This way, you can improve the association of documents to key process performers, editors and authors. Created by or Modified by are unlikely to cover all such ways to identify document usage and People & Group fields (which in turn open up the Filter by [Me] option in views)
- Does your organization have any focus and/or effort on process improvement and/or quality? Many SharePoint environments I see are modeled off of two ideas. First, we need to migrate from the network drive. Second, we need a way for teams to collaborate. Here's the thing, teams may collaborate, but most of the time they collaborate around repeatable processes. I always find it shocking when a "best practice" metadata taxonomy omits the concept of a tag for organizational process(s) the document belongs to.

These thoughts may be beyond the focus of a developer or SharePoint Admin. But they're as valid as prioritizing which functions you're going to automate. I always find that form really should follow function.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most feasilble solution would be to create folders on the basis of some logical value. It could be date, category or any other logical column in your list. 
Folders will help you organize data and will also prevent hitting the threshold.